# javascript animate-ScrollTop works randomly

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, coffeescript

I have a list 10 elements after 5 seconds the elements begin to be highlighted one after the other and the previous is being unhighlighted. When the highlighing reaches the last element it starts from the begining.
The highlighting is being done by adding a selected id to the element.
I am done until this point.

There are only 3 elements visible in the list the rest of them needs to be scrolled to.
This is where this is getting tricky. I have used:

```
scrollToSelected: =>
 nav = $("#selected")
 if nav.length
   $(@el).animate
     scrollTop: nav.offset().top
   , 1000
```

This script is doing the scrolling but not as expected, it scrolls randomly up and down just as it didn't knew the tops of the items.
where can the problem be?

I have tried outputting the `.offset().top` values in the console so the result is like this:

```
171
-627
731
-19
1131
-891
419
-299
1011
101
-891
419
-299
1011
101
-891
419
-299
1011
101
-891
419
-299
1011
101
-891
419
-299
1011
101
-891
419
-299
196.5
248.5
492.5
512.5
612.5
-414.5
```

Any thougths?

EDIT:
after changing offset to position I get these values:
These one are not so wild still,it doesn't scroll as expected, after the 3-4th element the selected one is somewhere bellow the visible ones

```
10
164
174
328
322
476
486
624
634
772
798
936
950
1100
1098
-1088
```

Comment: Is this list inside an `overflow:hidden` div or a direct child of the html page?

Comment: Its a list inside an overflow:hidden   And the content of the list is also rendered by javascript

Comment: Try using `nav.position().top` instead of `nav.offset().top`, the latter gives position relative to the document. But that still doesn't explain does wild values unless you were scrolling tha page simultaneously

Comment: I have added an edit using position as you recommended.

Comment: I think I have the solution, posting an answer now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments you need to use `.position()` instead of `.offset()` for teh relative offset instead of the document offset.

As the order is dropping after a few elements it sounds like you need to increment the `scrollTop()` and not just replace it. Give this (untested) code a go:

```
scrollToSelected: =>
  nav = $("#selected")
  if nav.length
    el = $(@el) 
    el.animate
      scrollTop: el.scrollTop() + nav.position().top
      , 1000
```

Comment: @LogofaT  Cheers, it's one of those things I remember dealing with myself a few months ago. And all tutorials that deal with these things are very convoluted. Happy Coding.